# Camera calibration and predict the eye focusing point on screen OpenCV / EmguCV

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

I have a project idea that check web usability using eye tracking. for that I needed to predict the focusing point on the screen(i.e. pixel points on screen) in specific time gap(0.5 second).

Here is some additional information:

I intended to use openCV or emguCV but it causing me a bit of trouble beacuse of my inexperience with OpenCV.

I am planning to "flatten" the eye so it appears to move on a plane. The obvious choice is to calibrate the camera to try to remove the radial distortion.

During the calibartion process the user looks at the corners of a grid on a screen. The moments of the pupil are stored in a Mat for each position during the calibration. So I have an image with the dots corresponding to a number of eye postions when looking at corners of a grid on the screen.

is there any article or example I can refer to get a good idea about this scenario and openCV eye prediction??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different methods of camera calibration are possible and (similar/as like to corner dots method) 
[Thesis work on Eye Gaze using C++ and openCV](http://www.cs.ru.ac.za/research/g09W0474/Thesis.pdf) and this should for sure help you.You can find some opencv based c++ scripts as well.

FYI : 
Some works are presented where it claims Eye Gaze without calibration

- Calibration-Free Gaze Tracking an experimental analysis by Maximilian Möllers
- Free head motion eye gaze tracking without calibration

[I am restricted to post less than 2 reference links]

Answer (score 0):

To get precise locations of eyes, you need first to calibrate your camera, using Chessboard approach or some other tools. Then you need to undistort the image, if it is not straight.

OpenCV comes already with an eye detector (Haar classifier, refer to eye.xml file), so you can already locate it and track it easily.

Besides that, there's only math to help you matching the discovered eye to the location it is looking at.